# create a shortcut links file or folder in MAC OS or Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos

In windows, pywin32 package can create a shortcut link to a directory or a file.
But how can I do this in MAC OS with python?
Which package or command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

[**Symlinks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) under *nix are created with [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.symlink).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os

link_name = 'linkname'
file_name = './filename'

# hard link
cmd = 'ln ' + file_name + ' ' + link_name
os.popen(cmd)

# soft link
cmd = 'ln -s ' + file_name + ' ' + link_name
os.popen(cmd)
```